# How to write a sql query select ros where there are id repeaeted twice in last hours? Have date and time column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have id, date,time(doenst have date) columns, and I am just wondering how to select rows where id repeated at least two other times(repeated three times) in last hour.. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66qc9.png)

Comment: please tag your sql engine? provide sample data and expected output

Comment: its mysql.. sorry its my first time posting questions.

Answer (score 0):

`select * from 'table' where date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) group by id having count(id) >= 2`
Will select records within last hour, group them by id and filter which group have more than 1 records

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: The question is what if date doesnt have time data.. do i just date+time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ?

Comment: You may change to `... where DATE(date) = CURDATE() and time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) group by ...`

Answer (score 0):

use `GROUP BY` query to get duplicate ID

```
select *
from 'table' 
where date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
group by id 
having count(id) >= 2
```

Comment: The question is what if date doesnt have time data.. do i just date+time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ?

Comment: One of these answers plagiarises the other. Which is which?